# Replacing data in one table with data from another table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 4 tables and 4 models.

Activity, Census, RequestBulk and EntityRequest.

I have recently created a new table RequestBulk. This table finds all the records in the Activity and Census table and mirrors their data. Any unique columns are inserted into the metadata field in the RequestBulk Table.

When an Activity or Census is created it will also create an EntityRequest record.
This EntityRequest record has a from_id column. This column is either the Activity ID or the Census ID.

What I am looking to do is create a rake task that will take the ID of the RequestBulk instead and replace the from_id data (replacing the Activity or Census ID).

Note - The RequestBulk table contains an RequestType field that is either 'Activity' or 'Census'.

Both Activity and Census have a `has_many :EntityRequests, as :parentable` relations.

I was thinking something like:

```
RequestBulk.all.each do |rb|
  if rb.request_type == 'BulkActivity'
    EntityRequest.update(from_id: rb.id)
  end
end
```

However, this simply just takes ID the last record in the RequestBulk table and updates all the records in the EntityRequest table with this ID.

Comment: Can this be handled on the database level instead with a view?

Comment: This would need to be down via a rake task such as this.

Answer (score 0):

```
data_table_1 = Table1.pluck(:id, :data)
data_table_2 = Table2.pluck(:id, :data)

data_table_1.each do |id, _|
  row_table_2 = data_table_2.find { |row| row[0] == id }
  Table1.find(id).update(data: row_table_2[1]) if row_table_2
end
```

I hope this may help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).